# c++ Class not working

Tags: c++, class

I'm working on a simple timer class and I don't know what the problem is.
I tried a few ways but I can't figure it out.

I know this question has already been asked, but can someone help me?

```
class timer
{
    int interval;
    int count;
    bool run;

public:
//constructor
    timer(int interval);
    ~timer()
    {
    }
    ;
    void start();
    void setInterval(int intv);
    void pause();
};
timer::timer(int intval)
{
    interval = intval;
}

void timer::start()
{
    run = true;
    while (run)
    {
        count++;
        if (count < interval)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            //reset timer interval
            count = 0;
            cout << "sdsds";
        }
    }
}
void timer::pause()
{
    run = false;
}
void timer::setInterval(int intv)
{
    interval = intv;
}
```

Comment: What, *exactly*, is the problem?

Comment: well when i call it it doesnt work

Comment: i declare a new object t(1000) and start it t.start(). It doesnt show the cout..

Comment: You're going to have to be *a lot* more specific than ‘*doesn't work*’. Does it not compile? Does it crash? What do you see when you debug it?

Comment: It doesnt cras hat all .The console appears , but it's not showing the cout...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that this

```
timer::timer(int intval)
{
interval =  intval;
}
```

should be this

```
timer::timer(int intval)
{
interval =  intval;
count = 0;
}
```

As far as I can see you aren't initialising `count`.

Comment: Phew! Good thing that did it. The only other suggestion was to take off and nuke the entire site from orbit. Still, it is the only way to be sure.